# Expo Webview Load local HTML file

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I'm trying to load an HTML file into react-native-webview using expo. My goal is to have my existing React codebase (built) converted to a mobile app.
[This example works on Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/cxfe4EJPc). It works on the Android  Online Simulator that Snack provides. But when I download the snack (download button on top right of snack - can only be clicked after you press ctrl+s) - and run it locally on my virtual android - it just loads the file as text.

What is the difference??

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";
import { useAssets } from "expo-asset";

export const MusicSheet = () => {
  const [index, indexLoadingError] = useAssets(
    require("../assets/musicsheetview/index.html")
  );

  const [html, setHtml] = useState("");

  if (index) {
    readAsStringAsync(index[0].localUri).then((data) => {
        setHtml(data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        onLoad={() => {}}
        source={{ html }}
        onMessage={(event) => {}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 100,
    display: "flex",
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is it in your code that answers the question?

Answer (score -1):

There is an other way to do it with expo asset:

```
const [assets, error] = useAssets([require('./../../assets/html/image.html')])
const [renderedOnce, setRenderedOnce] = useState(false)

const updateSource = () => {
    setRenderedOnce(true)
}

return (
    assets !== undefined &&
    error === undefined &&
    assets[0].localUri !== null && (
        <WebView
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={renderedOnce ? { uri: assets[0].localUri } : undefined}
            onLoad={updateSource}
        ></WebView>
    )
)
```

For android, we have to use the onLoad trick because of a wWbug (cf https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/656#issuecomment-561067913)